# errno without thread-local storage

Tags: c, glibc, libc, musl

I want to statically compile a program with [tcc](https://bellard.org/tcc/). tcc complains with `error: Unknown relocation type: 23`. This is [apparently](http://nongnu.13855.n7.nabble.com/error-Unknown-relocation-type-for-got-23-with-static-td240372.html) caused by my libc implementation (glibc 2.28-10) using thread-local storage to implement `errno`, which tcc does not support. The program that I'd like to compile does not use threads, and so it would not be a problem if `errno` was implemented as a global, which would fix it for tcc. Does anyone know if there's a libc implementation that can be configured to do this?

Comment: why tcc? -----------

Comment: why `-static`? What OS/environment? It's the OS in conjunction with the compiler that specifies how TLS is done. The _TL;DR:_ use `gcc` [and/or `clang`]. Or, try `tcc` _without_ `-static`

Comment: tcc has many benefits over gcc/clang, including a [demonstrable defense](https://dwheeler.com/trusting-trust/) for the [trust problem](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rdriley/487/papers/Thompson_1984_ReflectionsonTrustingTrust.pdf). static linking also [has many benefits](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/dynamic-linking/). Although these are large topics of discussion, that will quickly get off-topic here.